# I am trying to do a GET/POST request and defined the options variable twice. The second definition overrides the first

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, httprequest, urlfetch

I am trying to do a GET/POST request and defined the options variable twice. The second definition overrides the first, and my authorization token is only in the first.

Therefore when I make the request, I’m not passing the authorization token, which causes the "Login Required" error.

How do I fix this?

```
function DBMdownload() {
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclickbidmanager/v1/query/000000000";
  var options = {
    'method': 'get',
    'headers': {'Authorization': ('Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken())}
     };
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType' : 'application/json',
     };
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); 
var responseData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
}
```

UPDATE

```
function DBMdownload() {
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclickbidmanager/v1/query/608174710";
  var options = {
    'method': 'get',
    'headers': {'Authorization': ('Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken())}
     };
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

function DBMdownload2() {
  var options2 = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType' : 'application/json',
     };
var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var responseData = JSON.parse(response2.getContentText());
}
}
```

Comment: Read about object literal syntax. Perhaps you wanted to only change a specific property of the already-existing object

Comment: why do you need 2 method? do you want a get or a post for that url?

Comment: In other words, **why** do you expect *assigning a new definition* to **not** overwrite the previous assignment?

Comment: How can you use both `get` and `post` in the same request?

Comment: I wasn’t aware you couldn’t do a GET and POST in the same request. I’m using the get to get credentials and post to request the JSON.

Comment: The GET request is required to get an authorization token and the the POST is to use that token to get a JSON file.

Answer (score 3):

Bryan,

Your current approach is overriding the options object, that's why your call is not sending the token.

You can either split these functions to have a get and a post function sending the URL and other properties as parameters or remove the first declaration of the `options` object and add the `headers` to the last one.

Comment: Hi Flavio, I updated my code based on your recommendation. It still doesn’t seem to work.

Comment: Try to update your post method to:

```function DBMdownload2() {
  var options2 = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType' : 'application/json',
    'headers': {'Authorization': ('Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken())}
     };```